# MDX find period with max running total

Tags: mdx

I'm using the FoodMart database.
My objective is to find a period (ie time_id1 - time_id2) when the positive deviation (dev_sales) between sales in a given day and average sales is maximized. Deviation could be negative as well. It looks like the max subsequence problem, but can't find the way how solve it using mdx. Any ideas or advices? Am I missing something obvious?

```
with 
member avg_sales as AVG([Time].[Time Id].[Time Id],[Measures].[Store Sales])
member sales as [Measures].[Store Sales]
member dev_sales as sales- avg_sales,FORMAT_STRING='0.00'
member running_dev as
Sum((PeriodsToDate([Time].[DayMonthYear].[All].level,
[Time].[DayMonthYear].currentmember), dev_sales )), FORMAT_STRING='0.00'

Select {sales, avg_sales,dev_sales,running_dev} on 0, 
[Time].[Time Id].[Time Id]  on 1
From sales
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the same time hierarchy throughout:

```
WITH 
MEMBER avg_sales AS 
 AVG(
  [Time].[Time Id].[Time Id]
 ,[Measures].[Store Sales]
)
MEMBER sales AS [Measures].[Store Sales]
MEMBER dev_sales AS 
  sales- avg_sales
MEMBER running_dev AS
Sum(
NULL:[Time].[Time Id].currentmember
, dev_sales 
)
SELECT 
  {sales, avg_sales,dev_sales,running_dev} ON 0, 
  [Time].[Time Id].[Time Id]  ON 1
FROM sales;
```

Comment: May be I didn't catch the idea, but for me the result is the same.
Sum(NULL:[Time].[Time Id].currentmember, dev_sales ) calculates the same running total as PeriodsToDate.

Comment: @maty I used `[Time].[Time Id].currentmember` in the running total - in the hope of ensuring that currentmember works ok